# What should be the coil ratio to wirelessely transmit 12V/8A?

Tags: power

I am doing a project on wireless charging of a 40AH battery, for that I used step down transformer of 12V/8A that works fine, But now my concern is to replace transformer with coils which can give me same ratings as 12V/8A.

Comment: You should post schematics of the design. How are you going to position the transmission coil relatively to the receiving coil? What kind of distance between the coils are we talking about?
This step-down transformer is connected to the mains and gives 12VAC, is that right?

Comment: You want to transfer 8amps oO

Comment: @GleisonStorto Coils are going to be parallel to each other, yes it is connected to mains(220V) and gives 12V. Distance is 6-8 inches

Answer (score 1):

This has been discussed before, see:
[Inductive wireless mobile charger circuit](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/139050/inductive-wireless-mobile-charger-circuit)

Overall I suspect that trying to efficiently transfer 8A will very difficult.

For other references see:
http://www.low-powerdesign.com/120706-article-wireless-power-charging.htm

http://digitalcommons.calpoly.edu/cgi/viewcontent.cgi?article=1136&context=eesp

Here is a design you can experiment with:
https://www.mepits.com/project/171/DIY-Projects/-Wireless-Power-Transmission-Mobile-Charger-Circuit-Using-Inductive-Coupling

Comment: I like "very difficult" ... Sir, you have mastered the art of understatement!

Comment: Very difficult is still a world away from impossible.

Answer (score 0):

Can you loop half an iron (laminations,ferrite,whatever) core through each coil and join them up accurately in the charging cradle? Buy two transformer kits, use the E's and throw the I's away. I don't see a better option if you need any kind of efficiency.